# how to install petclinic in spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed the latest STS but it don't have any samples in it.

I want to test petclinic app but i don't know how to find and install it.

I have found this link
http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/downloads/detail?name=petclinic.zip&can=2&q=

But how can i import it in STS and link with database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to explore new Spring 3 functionality, there is a PetCare project updated with Spring 3 features. You can check out the project from [here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk/)

I used maven to build the project and it worked fine for me. I don't think PetClinic is maintained anymore for new releases.

Comment: sorry for that but how can i download that file , or how can i import to current sts

Comment: You can use any subversion plugin in STS to check out project directly into your workspace from the given URL.

Comment: i don't know much about sub version . is  that plugin pre installed in sts or i nned to install it

Comment: If you have a plugin installed you should be able to follow this path. 'File > Import > SVN > Checkout Projects from SVN'. If not quickly google for SVN plugin for STS and follow the install instruction.

Comment: Its now appearing on left side of project explorer. how can i run it to show its working. secondly now i dont want to have it linked online. can i just make a copy to work on it

Comment: It's your local offline copy, do as you please. I recommend building with Maven. All the necessary plugin to build this app with Maven ship with STS. If you are not familiar with Maven, have a look here http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html. This should get you up and running in no time. Offtopic, I would highly recommend reading up on version control system like Subversion or CVS. Sooner or later, you will have to use it regularly.